# Using by in parallel in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am a noob R programmer. I have written a code that needs to apply a function to a data frame split by factors. The data frame in itself contains about 1 million 324961 observations with 64376 factors in the variable that we use to slice the dataframe.

The code is as follows:

```
library("readstata13")
# Reading the Stata Data file into R
bod_fb <- read.dta13("BoD_nonmissing_fb.dta")

gen_fuzzy_blau <- function(bod_sample){

  # Here we drop the Variables that are not required in creating the Fuzzy-Blau index

  bod_sample <- as.data.frame(bod_sample)

  bod_sample$tot_occur <- as.numeric(bod_sample$tot_occur)
  bod_sample$caste1_occ <- as.numeric(bod_sample$caste1_occ)
  bod_sample$caste2_occ <- as.numeric(bod_sample$caste2_occ)
  bod_sample$caste3_occ <- as.numeric(bod_sample$caste3_occ)
  bod_sample$caste4_occ <- as.numeric(bod_sample$caste4_occ)


  # Calculating the Probabilites of a director belonging to a caste
  bod_sample$caste1_occ <- (bod_sample$caste1_occ)/(bod_sample$tot_occur)
  bod_sample$caste2_occ <- (bod_sample$caste2_occ)/(bod_sample$tot_occur)
  bod_sample$caste3_occ <- (bod_sample$caste3_occ)/(bod_sample$tot_occur)
  bod_sample$caste4_occ <- (bod_sample$caste4_occ)/(bod_sample$tot_occur)

  #Dropping the Total Occurances column, as we do not need it anymore
  bod_sample$tot_occur<- NULL

  # Here we replace all the blanks with NA
  bod_sample <- apply(bod_sample, 2, function(x) gsub("^$|^ $", NA, x))
  bod_sample <- as.data.frame(bod_sample)

  # Here we push all the NAs in the caste names and caste probabilities to the end of the row
  # So if there are only two castes against a name, then they become caste1 and caste2
  caste_list<-data.frame(bod_sample$caste1,bod_sample$caste2,bod_sample$caste3,bod_sample$caste4)

  caste_list = as.data.frame(t(apply(caste_list,1, function(x) { return(c(x[!is.na(x)],x[is.na(x)]) )} )))
  caste_list_prob<-data.frame(bod_sample$caste1_occ,bod_sample$caste2_occ,bod_sample$caste3_occ,bod_sample$caste4_occ)

  caste_list_prob = as.data.frame(t(apply(caste_list_prob,1, function(x) { return(c(x[!is.na(x)],x[is.na(x)]) )} )))

  # Here we write two functions: 1. gen_castelist
  #                              2. gen_caste_prob
  # gen_castelist: This function takes the row number (serial number of the direcor)
  #                and returns the names of all the castes for which he has a non-zero
  #                probability.
  # gen_caste_prob: This function takes the row number (serial number of the director)
  #                and returns the probability with which he belongs to the caste
  #
  gen_castelist <- function(x){
    y <- caste_list[x,]
    y <- as.vector(y[!is.na(y)])
    return(y)
  }

  gen_caste_prob <- function(x){
    z <- caste_list_prob[x,]
    z <- z[!is.na(z)]
    z <- as.numeric(z)
    return(z)
  }

  caste_ls <-list()
  caste_prob_ls <- list()
  for(i in 1:nrow(bod_sample)) 
  { 
    caste_ls[[i]]<- gen_castelist(i)
    caste_prob_ls[[i]]<- gen_caste_prob(i)
  }

  gridcaste <- expand.grid(caste_ls)
  gridcaste <- data.frame(lapply(gridcaste, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  gridcasteprob <- expand.grid(caste_prob_ls)

  # Generating the Joint Probability
  gridcasteprob$JP <- apply(gridcasteprob,1,prod)

  # Generating the Similarity Index
  gen_sim_index <- function(x){
    x <- t(x)
    a <- as.data.frame(table(x))
    sim_index <- sum(a$Freq^2)/(sum(a$Freq))^2
    return(sim_index)
  }
  gridcaste$sim_index <- apply(gridcaste,1,gen_sim_index)

  # Generating fuzzyblau
  gridcaste$fb <- gridcaste$sim_index * gridcasteprob$JP

  fuzzy_blau_index <- sum(gridcaste$fb)
  remove_list <- c("gridcaste","")
  return(fuzzy_blau_index) 

}

fuzzy_blau_output <- by(bod_fb,bod_fb$code_year,gen_fuzzy_blau)

# Saving the output as a dataframe with two columns
# Column 1 is the fuzzy blau index
# Column 2 is the code_year
code_year <- names(fuzzy_blau_output)
fuzzy_blau <- as.data.frame(as.vector(unlist(fuzzy_blau_output)))
names(fuzzy_blau) <- c("fuzzy_blau_index")
fuzzy_blau$code_year <- code_year

bod_fb <- merge(bod_fb,fuzzy_blau,by = "code_year")
save.dta13(bod_fb,"bod_fb_example.dta")
```

If the code is tl;dr, the summary is as follows:

I have a dataframe `bod_fb`. I need to apply the apply the `gen_fuzzy_blau` function on this dataframe by slicing the dataframe with factors of `bod_fb$code_year`.

Since the function is very huge sequential processing is taking more than a day and ends up in running out of memory. The function `gen_fuzzy_blau` returns a numeric variable `fuzzy_blau_index` for each code_year of the dataframe. I use `by` to apply the function on each slice. I wanted to know if there is a way to parallelly implement this code so that multiple instances of the function run at once on different slices of the dataframe. I did not find a `by` implementation for `parallel` package and I did not know how to pass the dataframes as iterators while using `foreach` and `doParallel` packages.

I have a AMD A8 laptop with 4GB RAM and windows 7 sp1 home basic. I have given 20GB as page file memory (this was after I got the memory error).

Thank you

**EDIT 1:** @milkmotel I have eliminated the redundancy in the code and removed the for loops, but a huge amount of time is being wasted in `gen_sim_index` in the function, I am using the `proc.time()`function to gauge the time that each part of the code is taking.

The function is supposed to the following to a row:
if we have a row (not a vector) say: `a a b c` the similarity index will be (2/4)^2 + (1/4)^2 + (1/4)^2 ie, summation of (no of occurences of each unique element of each row/total no of elements in the row)^2

I am unable to use the `apply` function directly on the row because each element in a row because each element in the row has different factors and `table()` does not output the frequencies properly.

What is an efficient way to code the `gen_sim_index` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saving your data 6 times over in 6 different variables. Try not doing that.

and it takes a day because you're running character indexing on a ridiculous amount of data with gsub().

Take your code out of your gen_fuzzy_blau function as it provides no value to wrap it up into one function rather than running it all independently. Then run it all one line at a time. If it takes too long to run, reconsider your method. Your code is incredibly inefficient.